# modelling repeated measures with correlated responses within groups

Tags: regression

I have a dataset which contains information on the average crime rate, population, average gas price and number of tesla charging stations - for different cities over different years. This is a repeated measures data. These cities belong to 5 different EU countries (ex: UK, Belgium, France, etc.). Data is aggregated at the city and year level. Ex: London 2018, London 2019, London 2020 ... Paris 2018, Paris 2019, etc.

I want to make a model which looks at which factors are associated with increases in the number of tesla charging stations. For example, I have a hypothesis that increasing gas prices might lead to more people buying electric cars and therefore result in the creation of more tesla charging stations.

What kind of model can I use here? Longitudinal regression for count data with mixed effects?

Comment: How many cities do you have and how many years ?

Comment: like 10 years of data, aprox 50 cities for each country (5 countries)

Comment: OK then I don't have anything to add to my answer below....

Answer (score 2):

> What kind of model can I use here? Longitudinal regression for count data with mixed effects?

That type of model could be suitable. Whether you treat the outcome as a count, where you might use a Poisson model, or treat it as continuous will depend on the data. I assume we are talking about hundreds if not thousands of charging points in each city, so treating it as continuous should be OK. Were you to fit such a model, the regression coefficient for gas price will tell you, with other variables left unchanged, the association between a 1 unit increase in gas price (or the logarithm of it if fitting a count model), and the number of charging points which would answer the research question that you posed. To handle repeated measures, you would fit random intercepts for cities nested in countries. With only 5 countries you might want to specify country as fixed, not random. To handle the autocorrelation you could fit random slopes for year, or explicitly use AR(1) for the within person residual covariance structure. If AR(1) isn't suitable then other structures such as Toeplitz, compound symmetry, heterogeneous versions of these or an unstructured covariance matrix can be considered.